# It's possible to use SQL COPY command on Spring Data Repository native query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a way to copy massive data from files using SQL COPY command on a JPA existent repository

Repository Code:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "COPY myschema.mytable FROM :file DELIMITER ',' CSV", nativeQuery = true)
    void copyDataFromCSVFile(@Param("file") String file);
}
```

Use of repository:

```
myRepository.copyDataFromCSVFile(file.getAbsolutePath();
```

But it generates next exception:

```
2023-04-14 18:43:59.288 DEBUG --- [http-nio-9051-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL : COPY myschema.mytable FROM ? DELIMITER ',' CSV
2023-04-14 18:43:59.292 TRACE --- [http-nio-9051-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [/tmp/myfile.csv]
2023-04-14 18:43:59.307 WARN --- [http-nio-9051-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-04-14 18:43:59.307 ERROR --- [http-nio-9051-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 34
2023-04-14 18:43:59.330 ERROR --- [http-nio-9051-exec-1] com.myapp.service.processor.FileProcessor : Errororg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

I was thinking that probably the issue was related with backslash character, so I tried to escape it (but it doesn't work either):

```
myRepository.copyDataFromCSVFile(file.getAbsolutePath().replace("/", "//"));
```